# JavaScript RegExp [^...] expression not giving intended result

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

Below is my code:

```
function isValid(passCode){
   var myRegExp=/[^a-z\d]/i;
   return !(myRegExp.test(passCode));
}

if (isValid(prompt("Enter passcode:",""))){
   alert("Access granted");
}else{
   alert("Denied");
}
```

As per my understanding, if I pass, for example, `abc` as a parameter to the `isValid()` function, `myRegExp.test` should return `true` and hence the `isValid()` should return `false` (as the `!` operator is used).
But the function returns `true`. Why?

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k7d4va5k/#&togetherjs=GCP5bmgPP4

Comment: ^ inside [] makes it "not" ... so `/[^a-z\d]/.test('abc')` will be false ... on the other hand `/^[a-z\d]/.test('abc')` is true because ^ in this case matches beginning of line (which is what I think you may have intended)

Comment: Are you sure about the validation. @Jaromanda was right. If you pass abc the myRegExp.test should return false

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Consider using a resource such as https://regex101.com/ to test out your regexps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets.

```
/[a-z\d]/
```

this waill match alphabets and digits

Typing a caret (`^`) after the opening square bracket negates the character class. The result is that the character class matches any character that is not in the character class. Hence

```
/[^a-z\d]/.test('abc') will be false

/^[a-z\d]/.test('abc') will be true
```

Because in the latter case the caret symbol indicates the beginning of a line that means if caret is used outside a character class it represents the beginning of the line instead of negating the character class.